# FormatCurrency giving different results on different pages in different browsers?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Given the following VBscript code:
`FormatCurrency("123",2)`
written to an html page:
`<td><%= FormatCurrency("123",2) %></td>`

Both pages have the same charset "ISO-8859-1", and show the same behavior with charset "UTF-8".

I am getting several results across browsers - IE10 and FireFox38 display the following:
"Payment Page": £123.00
"Receipt Page": Â£123.00

while in Chrome45 I receive:
"Payment Page": �123.00
"Receipt Page": £123.00

I've been staring at this problem for the better part of an hour, and I have no idea why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the charset.

Comment: Not sure it matters, but how is the charset specified (HTTP headers or meta tag)?

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel - in this case, it doesn't, but HTTP headers.

Comment: We observe that (1)The character encoding does not depend on the charset, and (2) The browser display does not depend on the character encoding. So: (a) is FormatCurrency evaluated server side? (b) is there any other locale information associated with the page? View page source and page headers for more information. See also https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cow-orker pointed this out to me, after having a similar issue:

Make sure your file is saved in the proper encoding! My file was saved in UTF-8 and needed to be encoded in ANSI (it's an old system).

Answer (score 0):

[Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake): **Â£** is `ANSI` interpretation of `UTF-8` encoded **£** (hexadecimal `0xC2 0xA3`). Next workaround could help:

```
<td><%= Replace(FormatCurrency("123",2),"£","&pound;") %></td>
```

or

```
<td><%= Replace(FormatCurrency("123",2),"£","&#163;") %></td>
```

See  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp